# Using an arbitrary plugin in Jenins 2 Pipeline scripts

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

Using the *Snippet Generator* tool in Jenkins 2, I can setup a plugin like I would within a job, and then it will generate me the Groovy I can use in my Pipeline script.

[image]

But what if the plugin I am interested in instrumenting isn't listed in the "Sample Step" drop down in the *Snippet Generator*? How do I determine how to create a script block to instrument the plugin I want to use?

In my case, I would like to use the "[Flexible Publish](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Flexible+Publish+Plugin)" plugin within my Pipeline script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use plugins which are not compatible with pipeline generally.
Plugins need to be modified more or less to be compatible.
See https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/COMPATIBILITY.md

Answer (score 2):

To be complete you need to know that snippet generator only shows compatible plugins that **declare a specific help page** in plugin's code. If we take the example of [docker-workflow](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-workflow-plugin) plugin, you can see in the code that it defines a [help page for DockerDSL](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-workflow-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/docker/workflow/DockerDSL/help.jelly), which means that a Snippet Generator will be available for DockerDSL step.

Therefore you should always check [Jenkins plugins compatibility page](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/COMPATIBILITY.md) (as arasio mentionned it) and not what you see in Snippet Generator.