# jenkins pipeline how to use plugin

Tags: jenkins, phpunit, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

Im just beginning to use jenkins pipeline plugin with a "Jenkinsfile", the base language of my project is php so i use testing tools like phpunit and others to generate reports, on other jenkins configurations the plugins fo phpunit to read junit output format and display graphs and statistics is really easy.

My question is how to use those old plugins inside pipeline plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40150468/702954). In short, if you want to use a specific plugin in your pipeline, you should first check if this plugin is pipeline-compatible in the [official compatability list](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/COMPATIBILITY.md). For example, if you are using JUnit you can see from the list that this plugin is pipeline-compatible.

For JUnit usage, you can check the well-documented [pipeline tutorial](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md#recording-test-results-and-artifacts).