# Can I use step() to create any build-step from any plugin?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, valgrind, jenkins-pipeline

I am currently trying to transform my former "GUI"-build-steps into a pipeline groovy script. I formerly had a step from the  [valgrind plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/valgrind-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/valgrind/ValgrindPublisher.java) to publish the results of a valgrind run.

I found the "step: General Build Step" function in the Pipeline Syntax Snippet Generator and tried to use it to create the valgrind publish results step with the following code:

```java
// file pipeline.groovy

import org.jenkinsci.plugins.valgrind.*;

...

node('Publish Valgrind results')
{
    step([$class: 'ValgrindPublisher', ValgrindPublisherConfig: [$class: 'ValgrindPublisherConfig', pattern: 'CppCodeBase/Generated/ValgrindOutput/**']])
}

...
```

When I run this jenkins complains:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: no known implementation of interface jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildStep is named ValgrindPublisher
```

So I am not sure if the problem is that `ValgrindPublisher` only derives from `BuildStep`and not from `SimpleBuildStep`or if my import is faulty.

**The more general question would be:**

Is it possible to run any build-step from a plugin in a pipeline script and if so, where can I find examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot. You can only use steps from [pipelines-compatible plugins](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/COMPATIBILITY.md) and it appears that your `ValgrindPublisher` plugin is not (yet) pipeline-compatible.

You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40150468/702954) for similar information.